# Python Recursive Summation of Nested Lists Big O Analysis

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

I have a function that sums the elements of a nested list.

```
data = [1, 2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]

#Big O for this is O(N)?
def sum_list_recursive(data):
    if len(data) == 0:
        return 0
    current_number = 0
    if isinstance(data[0], list):
        current_number = sum_list_recursive(data[0])
    else:
        current_number = data[0]
    data.remove(data[0])
    return current_number + sum_list_recursive(data)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Recursive sum: ", sum_list_recursive(data))
```

What would be the Big O for this? I think it's **O(N)**, because even though there's an if statement to go inside the nested list, it's still just calculating through the `N` elements. Also, what would be the Big Theta and Big Omega. Are they also just Theta(N) and Omega(N), because you can just multiply N by K?

Answer (score 1):

You're right as far as your argument goes.  However, look at what happens with arbitrary list nesting.  How many calls do you make if the input is as below?

```
data = [[[[[1]], [[[[2]]]]], [3, [[[4]]]], [[[5, 6]]]]]
```

It's still linear, but I believe it's linear on N+P, where N is the quantity of numbers to add, and P is the quantity of lists (left brackets, for example).

Comment: Awesome! Can you explain how the P works a little more or where I can find more info about it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  `P` isn't something that "works" -- it's merely the count of lists.

Comment: Sorry it was unclear. How do you know when to use P or when there will be a P?

Comment: Again, it's the count of lists.  Simply count the quantity of left parentheses; that's `P`.  In your posted example, P=3

Comment: Oh I see. I assume that at smaller counts like P=3 there's not much of a difference to big O with regards to nested lists so big O is just O(N) but at larger counts it is so O(N+P). Am I understanding that right?

Comment: This is not news.  If N << P, then it's essentially **O(P)**.  If P << N (the typical case), then it's essentially **O(N)**.  If you're curious, run some timing tests on a range of input cases.